# I need to pay for Domain Name in USD - How do I make payment in INR

Tags: india, usd-us-dollar, inr-indian-rupee

I want to buy a domain name from [eurodns](https://www.eurodns.com/) website. How can I pay money to them when I have only Indian currency(INR). i.e how to convert my money to USD.

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Do you have access to PayPal? They handle the exchange issue. I am in US, and buying from Euro denominated sellers is seamless.

Comment: Hi, i have paypal account but form to deposit money to paypal is not easy issue in india

Comment: Understood, I hope Dheer's suggestion helped. For me, Paypal is simple. I've seen exchange fees on my credit card and didn't even notice I was ordering from non-US sellers. A few % on a transaction. In my case for services I've bought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can pay via Indian Credit Card. The card company will convert the USD and charge you in Rupees.

And when there are enough Indian websites that do domain name registering, any specific reason you are looking at eurodns.

Comment: Hi thank for the suggestion .. i want to buy **.tm** domain. if you have any idea who sell .tm domain in indian rupees please commit to this

Comment: There are quite a few. http://www.101domain.in/ is one, please check other for rates. I have not used nor I am recommending any specific site.